# Can a three months old cat kill or hurt a kitten?

Tags: cats, animal-handling, farm-animals, service-animal

I have a 3 month old cat, and for a reason i had a 6 weeks kitten, when they meet they looks like they are fighting not playing although there's no hissing but the oldest cat looks like he's biting him, i'm just curious could he really hurt or kill the new kitten?

Answer (score 4):

Yes a 12 week old kitten can injure or kill a 6 week old kitten.

For a 12 week old kitten anything that moves is a toy so you need to keep the kittens apart at all times or the youngest one will get hurt or killed.

Kittens should only play with other kittens the same age(same litter)and very young kittens need to be protected against older cats unless it is their own mother.

Comment: Thanks mate i was really confused about that, that's helpful.